# Dynamically display images in D3

Tags: image, svg, d3.js

I want to display a series of images as an animation -- I'd use a GIF, except I want to manipulate specific frames.

I've displayed the image on an SVG canvas and now I want to change `xlink:href` dynamically.

```
function startAnimation(){
    c += 1;
    d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .attr("xlink:href", "images/image-" + c.toString() +".png")
        .each("end", startAnimation);       
};
```

This approach works fine if I try to change an attribute like image height, but it doesn't seem to work with the attribute `xlink:href`.

Is there a way to dynamically update images like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to preload and cache the images before you start the animation sequence. Otherwise, the images will be loaded lazily—and it's not unreasonable for an image to take 250ms to load, which means that by the time the image is loaded, you're on to the next frame.

For HTML elements, you can preload by creating Image objects (`new Image`), setting the `src` attribute, and then listening for load events (`onload`) to see when all the images are ready.  Browsers use the cached in-memory image when you set the `src` of a displayed HTML `img` element from a preloaded `Image`.

This technique may or may not work for SVG images, though. An even better technique is to use a sprite sheet, where you combine all the frames of your animation into a single image, which you then crop on the client. In HTML, you commonly use the background-position style for this; in SVG, you can do the same thing by clipping or overflow: hidden.

Yet another option is to create multiple `svg:image` elements and then hide all but one (e.g., via opacity or positioning the elements off-screen).

(Also, since you are not interpolating attributes, it might be simpler to use setInterval for your animation rather than d3.transition.)

Comment: Great -- I think the sprite sheet will work well for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
nodeEnter.append("svg:image")
     .attr('x',-9)
     .attr('y',-12)
     .attr('width', 15)
     .attr('height', 24)    
     .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { 
      if(d.Type=="name"){
       return "/images/icon-1.png";}
      else{
           return "/images/icon-2.png";}
           });
```